# React Object keys and values

Tags: reactjs, object, key, position, render

I have an object `conf` in React:

`Object.keys(conf)`:

```
0: "ubicacion1"
1: "ubicacion2"
```

`Object.values(conf)`:

```
0: "http://www.example1.es:8080"
1: "https://www.example2.es:8443"
```

How can I work or display each position of the Object?

Thank you

Comment: *How can I work or display each position of the Object?* could you elaborate on what this means?

Comment: What do you mean by "each position of the object"?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//work
conf.ubicacion1
//or
conf["ubicacion1"]


//log
console.log(conf.ubicacion1)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it gives me errors.

Couldn't loop through the Object?

Could you see it by position? 0, 1, ...

Comment: Please show me the output of `console.log(conf);`.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.